# MySQL select two tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, command

I have two tables and want to make a query. 
I tried to get team AA and team BB's image base on table A.

I used:

```
SELECT tableA.team1, tableA.team2, tableB.team, tableB.image,

FROM tableA 

LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.team1=tableB.team
```

The result only display imageA on the column. Are there any ways to select imageA and image B without using the second query? I appreciate any helps! Thanks a lot!

My table structure are:

table A

```
team1 team2
------------
 AA    BB
```

table B

```
 team  image
-------------
  AA   imagaA
  BB   imageB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
SELECT tableA.team1, tableA.team2, tableB.team, tableB.image, tb.image

FROM tableA 

LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.team1=tableB.team
LEFT JOIN tableB tb ON tableA.team2=tb.team
```